# Use find() in React JS

Tags: reactjs, find

is there anyway to use

> find(), findOneBy(), findBy()

in React JS?

I want to use it for array.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried already? Is there something that prevents you from using them?

Comment: Yes, the result is not what I expected. I suggest to use Linq. https://www.npmjs.com/package/linq

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. You ask how to use `find()`, then you suggest to use a partial reimplementation of .NET's object-relational mapping library. How does it help you to use `find()`? If the result is not what is expected, you should instead post: (1) your code, (2) expected result, (3) observed result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could definitely use it like this.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    var array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];
    var found = array1.find(function (element) {
      return element > 10;
    });

    return (<div>{found}</div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you EmCaye for your answer. The example is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are asking about to use `find(), findOneBy(), findBy()` as in getting records from some database?

In that case, you might have a bit of misunderstanding. The purpose of React is to handle your DOM, not doing operations to database (like Eloquent ORM on Laravel, for instance)

What you could do is have your web server handle those operations, while providing a REST API endpoints for your React app to hit.

Other than `find()`, none of those functions are part of javascript `Array.prototype`. You can do something like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].find(v => v === 3)
```

But you can not do the same with `findOne` and `findOneBy`.

Comment: Thank you Jackyef, your explanation is great. And yes, I am getting records from database using REST API.